# Append child can not work in two circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

When I do append two circles, I have nothing result. The following is my code. The first created circle which append in group is ok. But the next small circle which append in already created circle is shown nothing. I don't know what is wrong. I could appreciate any suggestions. Sorry for my English.

```
function drawCirc(x, y, r, id) {

var circ = document.createElementNS(svgURI, 'circle');
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', r);
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#CCFFCC');
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#6BC1C8');
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5');
circ.setAttribute('id', id);

// to add small circle
var circStart = document.createElementNS(svgURI, 'circle');
circStart.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', (x-5));
circStart.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', (y-10));
circStart.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 8);
circStart.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'blue');
circStart.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#E6F1DB');
circStart.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '2');

document.getElementById(group).appendChild(circ);

document.getElementById(id).appendChild(circStart);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest circles (or any other shapes) in SVG. You need to make them all children of containers such as `<g>` or `<svg>` elements.

In your case you likely want to change the last line of the code to

```
document.getElementById(group).appendChild(circStart);}
```